# OpenShift - Running containers as root in minishift

Tags: docker, openshift, root, minishift

I want to run a container, in `minishift`, from Docker Hub as described in this [article](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-any-docker-image-running-in-your-own-openshift-cluster/). Since the image in Docker Hub runs as `root` and OpenShift does not allow running containers as root, I am using this command to override this constraint. I am logged in as `system:admin`.

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

Firstly, it is not clear, which resource is missing, Secondly, is the override applicable in `minishift` at all? The `anyuid` SCC does exist.

```
oc get scc
NAME               KIND
anyuid             SecurityContextConstraints.v1.security.openshift.io
hostaccess         SecurityContextConstraints.v1.security.openshift.io
hostmount-anyuid   SecurityContextConstraints.v1.security.openshift.io
hostnetwork        SecurityContextConstraints.v1.security.openshift.io
nonroot            SecurityContextConstraints.v1.security.openshift.io
privileged         SecurityContextConstraints.v1.security.openshift.io
restricted         SecurityContextConstraints.v1.security.openshift.io
```

Comment: What do you get for `oc get sa` on that namespace? And what namespace are you working in?

Comment: By namespace, you mean the project name for `oc project`? I have set it to a project that will hold the Docker container image. And, on that namespace, `oc get sa` shows, names as `builder`, `default` and `deployer`.

Comment: Run `oc adm policy` command with `--loglevel 9` and see at what request it is failing.

Comment: The `system` user does not seem to have access. With `admin` user, the command `oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default --loglevel 9` produces this output: https://pastebin.com/LFtNJmfA

Comment: How exactly are you logging in as the cluster admin user. Minishift will accept any username and password, so if not doing it correctly you could be logging in as normal user. The usual way you would do this is as `developer` user run `oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default --as system:admin`. That is, use `--as` to do impersonation.

Comment: Followed your instructions on `--as`; same error: `Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource`.

Comment: Do you definitely have the matching `oc` client version for the cluster version? What do you get for `oc version`? That command should work so if it doesn't there is either a client mismatch or something mucked up in the Minishift install. And what do you get for `oc whoami`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200296/discussion-between-cogitoergosum-and-graham-dumpleton).

Comment: Note that the latest Minishift is for OpenShift 3.11 (Kubernetes 1.11). If you have an older version you need to upgrade.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I re-installed `oc` with `brew`. Now, I am able to set the permission! Please add this as an answer so that I can accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to log in as `system:admin` which you will have from the master nodes (root user).

(If you want to do admin operations remotely, you can assign cluster-admin role to individual user using the below command from master nodes `oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin <user>`)

First, create a ServiceAccount (SA) in the project.

```
oc project <project>
oc create sa nfs-sa
```

Add the Security Context Constraints to the SA.

`oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged -z nfs-sa`

Then, Mention the serviceaccount into the deploymentconfig/pod config in `spec` section.

```
serviceAccount: nfs-sa
serviceAccountName: nfs-sa
```

Thanks.